# Webpage rendered differently in IIS6 and IIS7

Tags: html, iis-7, internet-explorer-8, iis-6

We are using IIS 7 in development environment. All the pages are rendered more or less the same in Firefox and IE8 in IIS 7. But when I deployed to test which runs on IIS6, the pages appear different on IE8 (they work fine on Firefox). They appear dramatically different.

I used IE web dev tools to see what styles are getting applied, it seems a few styles are overridden differently although the CSS file are exactly the same on both environments. Since the webpages appear fine on IE8 (on IIS 7), I believe its an IIS 6 issue.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Is the server version the only thing that is different? I would guess that this might be an Intranet / Internet zone thing that is switching IE in and out of compatibility mode.

Comment: try using a tool like Fiddler to capture the raw output from the HTTP response on both sides, and compare the two. Also, what technologies are you using to generate the pages? ASP.net? Are your versions for all of that side of things the same on both platforms?

Comment: @David - heh. yep, I'll bet that is the problem.

Comment: I got the answer. The compatability mode was getting set for the test site. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Hello - did you ever resolve this problem? I know it has been a long time but I am having a similar problem. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761260/why-is-page-not-rendering-properly-missing-content-on-ie8-via-iis6