# Why is page not rendering properly (missing content) on IE8 via IIS6?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, internet-explorer-8, iis-6

Having a very annoying problem where custom user controls do not appear at all in my ASP.NET project when using IE8 and IIS6.

It works on all other browsers except IE8 when using ISS6.

When using exact same project on IE8 with ISS7, it works on all browsers including IE8.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is the content encapsulated in a certain tag, or included in a unique way (other language, etc.)?

I'm guessing there is a mime type or other configuration change between the two server instances, rather than it being a version conflict.

Why other browsers don't see the problem kind of hints away from that, but without additional details its hard to help more.

Comment: What other details you need?

Comment: Which part of the page is not displaying or which page types are not appearing?

Comment: Custom user controls are not appearing.